# inherited template constructor not called

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor, c++17

I am researching a design for a project and I have an issue to overcome. Basically I need the template constructor of visitor_interfaces_t to be called. Below is a simplified example of how the system works syntactically. The "large scale" project is located at https://github.com/amatarazzo777/ux_gui_stream and is in development by myself. The objects are organized to be easily created and also maintained. So I do like the syntax of how coordinate_t is written. However, it is not functioning as I planned. What is the proper way to inherit visitor_interfaces_t and allow the template param pack constructor to it to be called? C++17 dialect. Any other rigorous dissection is also welcomed, such as better design.  Thanks in advance for help.

I did find another solution to this question. I decided to break up the process of broadcasting the interface position and resolving the member function to the implementation.

template header file (templates_inherit.h)

```
/**
  templates_inherit.h

*/

#ifndef TEMPLATES_INHERIT_H_
#define TEMPLATES_INHERIT_H_

typedef int cairo_t;
typedef double PangoLayout;
class system_base_t {
public:
  system_base_t() {
    if (!visitor_dispatch_bound)
      ;
  }
  virtual ~system_base_t() {}

  bool visitor_dispatch_bound = false;
};

template <typename T, typename TC, typename... Args>
class class_storage_emitter_t : public TC,
                                public Args...,
                                public system_base_t {
public:
  using TC::TC;
  class_storage_emitter_t() {}

  class_storage_emitter_t(const class_storage_emitter_t &other) : TC(other) {}

  class_storage_emitter_t(class_storage_emitter_t &&other) noexcept
      : TC(other) {}

  class_storage_emitter_t &operator=(const class_storage_emitter_t &other) {
    TC::operator=(other);
    return *this;
  }

  class_storage_emitter_t &operator=(class_storage_emitter_t &&other) noexcept {
    TC::operator=(other);
    return *this;
  }

  virtual ~class_storage_emitter_t() {}
};

typedef std::function<void(cairo_t *)> fn_emit_cr_t;
typedef std::function<void(PangoLayout *)> fn_emit_layout_t;

typedef std::variant<std::monostate, fn_emit_cr_t, fn_emit_layout_t>
    fn_emit_overload_t;

class visitor_interface_t {
public:
  fn_emit_overload_t fn = {};
  std::size_t pipeline_order = {};
  virtual void bind_dispatch(system_base_t *ptr) {}
};

class visitor_interfaces_base_t {
public:
  visitor_interfaces_base_t() {}
  virtual ~visitor_interfaces_base_t() {}

  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, visitor_interface_t *>
      accepted_interfaces = {};
};

template <typename... Args>
class visitor_interfaces_t : public visitor_interfaces_base_t, public Args... {
public:
  visitor_interfaces_t() : Args(this)... {}
};

// abstract classes. started having problems when I added
// "interface" function (clue)
template <std::size_t ORDER> class abstract_emit_cr_t : visitor_interface_t {
public:
  abstract_emit_cr_t(visitor_interfaces_base_t *ptr) {
    pipeline_order = ORDER;
    ptr->accepted_interfaces[std::type_index(typeid(fn_emit_cr_t))] = this;
  }
  void bind_dispatch(system_base_t *ptr) {
    fn = fn_emit_cr_t{std::bind(&abstract_emit_cr_t::emit,
                                dynamic_cast<abstract_emit_cr_t *>(ptr),
                                std::placeholders::_1)};
  }
  virtual ~abstract_emit_cr_t() {}
  virtual void emit(cairo_t *cr) = 0;
};

template <std::size_t ORDER>
class abstract_emit_layout_t : visitor_interface_t {
public:
  abstract_emit_layout_t() {}
  abstract_emit_layout_t(visitor_interfaces_base_t *ptr) {
    pipeline_order = ORDER;
    ptr->accepted_interfaces[std::type_index(typeid(fn_emit_layout_t))] = this;
  }
  void bind_dispatch(system_base_t *ptr) {
    fn = fn_emit_layout_t{std::bind(&abstract_emit_layout_t::emit,
                                    dynamic_cast<abstract_emit_layout_t *>(ptr),
                                    std::placeholders::_1)};
  }
  virtual ~abstract_emit_layout_t() {}
  virtual void emit(PangoLayout *layout) = 0;
};

const int order_render_option = 3;

class coordinate_storage_t {
public:
  coordinate_storage_t() {}
  coordinate_storage_t(double _x, double _y, double _w, double _h)
      : x(_x), y(_y), w(_w), h(_h) {}
  coordinate_storage_t(double _x, double _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
  virtual ~coordinate_storage_t() {}
  double x = {};
  double y = {};
  double w = {};
  double h = {};
};

/**
 * classes are named and manufactured like so.
 * the parameterized nature of the syntax yields
 * a very maintainable source base.
 */
using coordinate_t = class coordinate_t
    : public class_storage_emitter_t<
          coordinate_t, coordinate_storage_t,
          visitor_interfaces_t<abstract_emit_cr_t<order_render_option>,
                               abstract_emit_layout_t<order_render_option>>> {
public:
  using class_storage_emitter_t::class_storage_emitter_t;
  coordinate_t() {}

  void emit(cairo_t *cr) { std::cout << "emit cr" << std::endl; }
  void emit(PangoLayout *layout) { std::cout << "emit layout" << std::endl; }
};

#endif /* TEMPLATES_INHERIT_H_ */
```

template_inherit.cpp

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <variant>

#include "templates_inherit.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  coordinate_t pos = coordinate_t{10, 10, 500, 500};
  pos.init_dispatch();

  cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << " " << pos.w << " " << pos.h << endl;
  cairo_t dummy_cr = 1;
  PangoLayout dummy_layout = 2;

  for (auto n : pos.accepted_interfaces) {
    std::visit(
        [&](auto &&arg) {
          using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
          if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, fn_emit_cr_t>)
            arg(&dummy_cr);
          else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, fn_emit_layout_t>)
            arg(&dummy_layout);
        },
        n.second->fn);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. What is it meant to do? What is the error?

Comment: You don't pass any arguments that would go to `visitor_interfaces_t(Args &... args)`.  The four arguments you pass go directly to `coordinate_storage_t` and no constructor for `class_storage_emitter_t` is ever called because `class_storage_emitter_t` doesn't have a constructor that takes four arguments.  Where would the arguments for `visitor_interfaces_t(Args &... args)` come from if you don't pass them in?

Comment: n. pronouns. Sorry for the code amount, I wanted to be sure that the complete architecture would be in there. The code is meant to name objects that may be inserted into a stream using the << operator which another part of the code base not included here. I have several objects that a user may instantiate to provide gui output using Cairo and Pango. So for example, there is a text_font_t, a text_color_t, and image_block_t.

Comment: Jerry, I thought that the arguments would come from the inheritance list within the class declaration. But you are right, the template constructor is never called. How could I encapsulate the class so that the definition maintains the visitor_interfaces_t and have it call it locally?

Comment: n. pronouns. these objects relate to different parts of the rendering stage. that is the font should be loaded and created before it is used. some objects have different meanings to parts of the rendering stage hence the render order is mentioned. The interface published provides a visitor pattern.

Comment: @AnthonyMatarazzo Use `@username` to reply to people, otherwise they won't get notifications. You always get notifications because the comments are under your own post.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh, thanks for information.